# How to create a deployable in rails like [war in java]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

Hi i am new to ruby on rails
I am from java platform

I want to deploy a rails application on thin server.

Que : what is the deployable output for rails app ? How to create a deployable in rails like [war in java]

Comment: just type in `rails s` in your application root directory and hit `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: i have to deploy in production .

Comment: Check [this](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy/). We keep our code on github and use heruku and engineyard which pulls the code and deploy.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby does not have packed executable files. A ruby app consists of many *.rb files that are compiled by the ruby vm/interpreter at runtime. The easiest deployment is to just copy the project as is to the server. There are however some deployment gems, that make your life easier. Take a look at `capistrano` or `vlad`. Here is a simple tutorial for capistrano: http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look into `warbler` <- this is what we use for production. Warbler will package your project as a `WAR` file which you can then deploy on a web server.

I cannot speak to the other suggestions, however I am sure they are also valid :) I have just never used them. I have never had an issue using warbler (http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/). It comes as a gem which you just need to install (`gem install warbler`) and then you can add warbler to your rake tasks:

In `lib/tasks` create `warbler.rake` file:

```
begin
  require 'warbler'
  Warbler::Task.new
rescue LoadError
  # not installed
end
```

Then you can run something like `rake war` and warbler should create a war file for you. If you don't like the warbler defaults, you can also specify your own config file to specify how the ruby files get packaged.

Comment: Please note, that warbler uses jruby to execute the app, so make sure, that your applications is working with jruby before using warbler.

Comment: i am running on ruby on rails not on JRuby

Comment: Good point @drexin - we do use jruby and thus the decision to go with warbler :)